# Can __repr__ return a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to make `__repr__` in the code below return a dataframe?

The code below will throw

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type DataFrame)
```

because - I guess - `__repr__` has to return a string.

Or should I replace `__repr__` with some other magic method?

```
import pandas as pd

class Query():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.df
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'some_filename'
    query = Query(filename)
    print(query)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Could this be an [XY problem](http://www.xyproblem.info)? There may be a better approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `__repr__` to return a string, which would be the representation of your dataframe. So, just do:

```
def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.df)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would want to return an object (to be able to process it) rather than its string representation.

Comment: Then you have it in `your_query.df`. Printing the represenation of the underlying df and using it as it is are two really different things.

Comment: @barciewicz that doesn't make any sense. `repr` is supposed to return a string, why do you want it to do something else? What do you imagine yourself to be able to do?